# How can we find the ip address of roscore?

Tags: ros, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can we find the ip address of roscore if multiple machines are connected

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257868/how-can-we-find-the-ip-address-of-roscore?/) by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2017-03-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, so  I just saw the running ROS will actually give tell you the ROS_MASTER_URI as well.

---

Originally posted by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) with karma: 112 on 2017-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2